# Invalid conversion of const to const char*, how do I fix it? Fails with gcc7

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

This compiles with older versions of gcc, but fails with GCC 7 with C++17.
This is the error I get:

> error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] end_of_line = '\0';

Can't seem to resolve this compilation error.

This is the code:

```
/*!
 * \brief Find the beginning of the next line in the given buffer.
 *
 * \param[in] str buffer to search for the beginning of the next line
 * \param[inout] ctx
 * \parblock
 * pointer to the end of the line (saved by this method)
 *
 * This pointer must be valid, and it must be set to NULL by the caller the first time.
 * \endparblock
 *
 * \return a pointer to the first character in the next line, or NULL if we have already hit EOF
 */
const char* Foo::GetNextLine(const char* str, const char** ctx)
{
    if(str == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Save a pointer to the end of the line (first time, it should be set to NULL by the caller).
    const char*& end_of_line = *ctx;
    if(end_of_line && *end_of_line == '\0')
    {
        end_of_line = '\0';
        return NULL;
    }

    // The start of this line is one character after the end of the last one.
    const char* start_of_line = end_of_line ? end_of_line + 1 : str;

    // Are we at the end of the whole thing?
    if(*start_of_line == '\0')
    {
        end_of_line = '\0'; // Reset the context state to get ready for the next load!
        return NULL;
    }

    // Read forward to the end of the line.
    end_of_line = start_of_line;
    while(*end_of_line != '\n')
    {
        if(*end_of_line == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        ++end_of_line;
    }

    return start_of_line;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the command and the output of your gcc call?

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 (as amended by a Defect Report), you can't assign an arbitrary zero valued expression to a pointer. It has to be either the constant `0` or an object of type `nullptr_t`, which is `nullptr`. This can be hidden behind the macro `NULL`.

The expression `end_of_line = '\0';` tries to assign a character constant to a pointer. This is no longer allowed. Assuming your intent is to NULL out the original pointer, you should change the line to read

```
end_of_line = nullptr;
```